# Make NSDictionary Monthwise from DateArray

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I have an array of DateString , in which I have values of date,month and year .

Now I have sorted it in ascending order . Now I have to put it in to dictionary with this key-value pair :-

**Key**- "January" (Month Name) and **Value**:- array of dates in that month

can anyone suggest me how to do this ?

Comment: Why do you have an array of date strings instead of `NSDate` objects?  That will make this task, and every other task involving that array, much easier...

Comment: Because it is coming from the webserive , I mean date , we have made a model in which they are getting the value of so many things . One of them is date , so we have kept it into nsstring format . will it help here if I have NSDate instead of NSString ?

Comment: Yep; always store data using the most appropriate data type.

Comment: Ok . Let me make them array of NSDate . But then also I will have an array containing NSDate object .. how then I make that dictionary described above ?

Comment: Well firstly you probably mean a dictionary of arrays unless you are certain there is only one date for each month?

Comment: @trojanfoe, converting to NSDate means that determining the month is a non-trivial task.

Comment: @gnasher729 No it doesn't, it makes it an easier task.  Unless of course that is *all* this array will be used for; in that case breaking it down to integer day/month/year will make the task easier.

Comment: No there can be zero,one or more than one date for each month

Comment: @trojanfoe .. so it will be dictionary of arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

        // Set your year and month here
        [components setYear:2016];

        NSMutableDictionary *dayAndMonthWiseList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for (int i=1; i<=12; i++)
        {
            [components setMonth:i];

            NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
            NSRange range = [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth forDate:date];
            NSMutableArray *dayList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] mutableCopy];

            for (int j=1; j<=range.length; j++)
            {
                [dayList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j]];
            }
            [dayAndMonthWiseList setObject:dayList forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
        }
        NSLog(@"Dic. :%@",dayAndMonthWiseList);
```

Result is :

```
Dic. :{
    1 =     (
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30,
        31
    );
    10 =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30,
        31
    );
    11 =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30
    );
    12 =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30,
        31
    );
    2 =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29
    );
    3 =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30,
        31
    );
    4 =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30
    );
    5 =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30,
        31
    );
    6 =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30
    );
    7 =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30,
        31
    );
    8 =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30,
        31
    );
    9 =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You write code, as everyone would do.

You need a dictionary that maps (year, month) to (array).

You start with an empty mutable dictionary. Then you loop through your items. For each item, get the year and month (I assume you don't want Januarys of different years together). Look up the year / month in the dictionary, getting the mutable array value. If it isn't there, add the (year, month) key with a new mutable array as the value. So now you have an array for the (year, month), and add the item to that array.

If your data is fixed at that point, you can iterate through the dictionary and replace all the mutable arrays with immutable arrays (just use copy). And instead of sorting all the items first, just sort the keys of the dictionary, so you are now sorted by month and year, then sort the arrays when you need them sorted. For example in a tableview, you only need those arrays sorted that are actually being displayed.